# Convert two separate Sets to a 2D array

Tags: java, swing, collections, jtable, set

I have two Sets of Strings, with each in the following format:

```
Set1(Names)  Set2(Sizes)

Pics         450 KB
Videos       50 MB
Music        32 MB
```

The two Sets are LinkedHashSets, so order is guaranteed. The Sets are also guaranteed to be the same size.

I need to show these two Sets in a JTable in the format above. Naturally, the simplest way to do it would be to create a 2D array, but I'm getting confused as to the order of each.

What is the best way to do it? Ideally, it would not require iteration through the Sets, but normally, the Sets' size is less than 10.

Comment: What strings are actually contained in the sets?

Comment: @aioobe Examples of the Strings are in the example table I posted

Comment: So `"Pics"` is one element in the set? Or `"Pics  450 KB"`? Or is it `"Pics  450 KB\nVideas   50 MB\nMusic  32 MB"`?

Comment: @aioobe edited to show the sets(as I understand them from the question) more clearly.

Comment: BTW: Why the "don't want iterator" restriction?

Comment: Apologies if it isn't clear. `Pics` is an element in the Set `Names`, while `450 KB` is an element in the Set `Sizes`

Comment: @SJuan76 I don't have a problem with the Iterator per sé, but, ideally, I'd be able to use something like Set.toArray to achieve my result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create a 2D array - see [DefaultTableModel.addColumn](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#addColumn%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29).  So you can use:

```
JTable table = new JTable();
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
model.addColumn("Names", s1.toArray(new String[0]));
model.addColumn("Sizes", s2.toArray(new String[0]));
```

Sorry if syntax is slightly off - not at an IDE right now.

Comment: I ended up doing something else (building the array right away, instead of using intermediate Sets), but this is my favourite answer, and one that's very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
Set<String> namesSet = ...;
Set<String> sizesSet = ...;
String[] names = namesSet.toArray(new String[namesSet.size()]);
String[] sizes = sizesSet.toArray(new String[sizesSet.size()]);
String[][] namesAndSizes = {names, sizes};
```